# Can a restful api return a page as a response?

Tags: rest, api, http, web-applications

I understand that an api is an application programming interface meaning it’s the interface between two or more programs or applications and it allows for communication across them through requests and responses.

Usually when people say api they think of a third party api such as one to get the weather or currency exchange and those usually will return data in JSON or XML and what not. However correct me if I’m wrong but how the client or front end interacts with the server or backend is also considered an api right? For instance when I submit a form on my webapp as a get request the url will change adding the parameters and basically my api for my web app or server will handle specific url or api endpoints and will return a response like rendering a webpage or returning a view.

My question is, is my understanding of this correct and if this way of interacting between my frontend and backend of my web app is considered an api and supposing it conforms with the RESTful constraints is it considered restful despite the fact that it doesn’t return raw data like in JSON and rather renders a webpage with html css JavaScript as a response? Or is it only a RESTful api if it conforms with the constraints and only returns raw JSON or similar data formats as most third party APIs for external use do?

Answer (score 3):

API is a terrible piece of terminology - and I think it has caused some confusion here.

First to be direct - yes, a restful api can 'return a page' as a response - but you are misunderstanding how webpages get rendered.

Web Browsers 'render' webpages. All they receive from a web-server when you type in `https://youtube.com` is data as text/html, which is then up to the browser to interpret in whatever way it likes/make it look pretty. There's actually not a ton of difference between sending a text/html file or a json one via an http request - the term 'raw' data doesn't really make any sense here - all data is raw data when it is in transit.

Comment: So my understanding of APIs is correct though like how a frontend of your webpage interacts with your backend via url endpoints is considered an api right? I see what you mean like in express/node I would just say render this html page but what you’re saying is basically what gets sent to the client side is just the html and text and the client side decides how to show it with css and stuff? But the css and js still gets sent to client side by the server doesn’t it? but like it’s processed with the html/text on the client side is that what you mean?

Comment: That is technically correct yes, though it is a Web API rather than a regular API. A Web API defines 'endpoints' or 'URI' which point to the things sent by the server when a request is made on that 'endpoint'.

There is a point of semantic confusion - there is a function in express literally called 'render', but all it really does it send data to the client - the web-browser on the client-side does the actual 'rendering'. You're right that the css and js gets sent at the same time (virtually).

Comment: But why is that called a web api like wouldn’t a “regular” or a third party api used to get like weather data or what not in JSON also use the same way of handing requests at certain endpoints with certain query parameters and sending back a response. Is the major difference between these two is that a web api is like kind of an internal api made specifically to show visual data for this one app whereas a regular api is made to respond with JSON data in format usually used by other applications where they handle and do all the processing and visualization for their application.

Comment: Like you said that even “rendering” a page is really just sending html data and the static files to the client and then they render it and show it there, so why is this called a web api? Is it just because of the use case ?

Comment: It's called a web api because the channel of communication is http/https. 

Debatably you could maybe call communication using other application layer protocols still 'web' apis, because you can communicate over the web in many more ways than just http/https, they just tend to be http/https.

Answer (score 2):

[REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is the collection of architectural constraints that shaped the world wide web.

In a sense, the original form of REST *is* returning HTML with links to CSS and javascript.

Stefan Tilkov's [2014 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM) covers some of the advantages of HTML representations of resources.  See also [Jon Moore 2010](https://vimeo.com/20781278).

Comment: Okay that kinda of clears things up. It’s just confusing how most people when they refer to a restful api they are usually talking about those external apis like Facebook twitter or some weather api that returns JSON but using what you said that means the API that I use in my web app to handle requests made from my front end to my backend to url endpoints that return a response in this case HTML with links to css and js can also be considered RESTful if I am using http and certain constraints like every transaction is the same etc right